# Copy & Paste/insert rows - pasting more data than was copied

Tags: excel, copy-paste, bulkinsert, vba

I have a macro that is set to copy all rows with data from columns A through D in Sheet 1 and paste it into columns A-D in Sheet 2, inserting it above data that is already in Sheet 2. The idea is to create an ongoing list with the most recent data at the top.

This was working perfectly fine, until today - not sure what changed, I haven't altered the macro in any way.

It is operating as it should, but then it takes the data that was copied and pastes it perpetually across all columns in excel.

So say I have X rows of data in columns A, B, C & D. The macro is correctly taking this data and pasting it from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 as it should. But then it is also pasting this data across every column (to column XFD).

So every 4 columns has the same data as A/B/C/D, until excel runs out of columns.

Why is it doing this? How do I stop this from happening?

### Macro:

```
Sub CopyData()
    Dim i As Integer
        i = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Value  'E1 counts # of rows w/ data
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D" & i).Copy  
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate  
        Rows("2:2").Select  
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown  
        Application.CutCopyMode = False  
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Activate
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try running only the portion of the macro which copies the desired data, then paste it into the sheet in the way you need it to and see if you get the same result, it may be trying to autofill the entire width of the selection.

Comment: You are copying four columns and pasting into 16,384 columns. You are going to have to insert a new row, then copy hte source and use the top-left cell of the destination as the destination.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is working now. I'm not sure why it was working before, but regardless - it's working now.

Comment: Were you previously only copying 3 columns, and you changed it to copy 4 columns today?  That would cause the change in behaviour (because 16384 is not a multiple of 3).

Answer (score 2):

You are copying four columns and pasting into 16,384 columns. You are going to have to insert a new row, then copy the source and use the top-left cell of the destination as the destination.

```
Sub CopyData()
    Dim i As Integer, dim ws1 as worksheet

    set ws1 = worksheets("sheet1")
    i = ws1.Range("E1").Value  'E1 counts # of rows w/ data

    with worksheets("sheet2")
       .rows(2).resize(i, .columns.count).Insert Shift:=xlDown 
       ws1.Range("A2:D" & i).Copy destination:=.cells(2, "A")
       .Activate
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to specify a cell, rather than an entire row, as the location for where I wanted to paste the copied data. This works now.